# Can I benefit from using a real axle as a shaft of a brushless motor on my RC car?

Tags: motors

I'm designing an RC car and considering two options now. I can put some gears into it, so that I would have a certain gear ratio between motor and axle, or I can remove shaft from the motor and, instead, put in the axle with wheels on. I want to avoid overheating of the motor primarily, and if it's ok, it would be great to raise the output power. So I want to ask whether the motor based on the axle would overheat or not, and is this way beneficial in terms of speed and construction?

Comment: This can't really be answer without further information, but you'll almost certainly want _some_ sort of gearing, else you'll get uselessly spinny wheel RPM but not enough torque to actually move the car. This _could_ be in form of a motor with built-in planetary gearing, and then you could indeed use the motor shaft as part of the axle, but else not. Probably you should design proper gearing yourself, and calculate the best ratio for whatever terrain the car is supposed to drive on.

Comment: I am assuming the design will have a microcontroller. So in order to manager overheating a temperature sensor can be placed to monitor the temperature.